# What these make messages mean while compiling sane-backends?

Tags: compilation, makefile, sane

I tried to compile the sane-backends from source but getting the following messages after running make, to configure I ran ./configure --enable-avahi BACKENDS='canon genesys test'

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/.../sane-backends/po'
Making all in testsuite
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/.../sane-backends/testsuite'
Making all in sanei
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/.../sane-backends/testsuite/sanei'
run 'make check' to run tests
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/.../sane-backends/testsuite/sanei'
Making all in tools
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/.../sane-backends/testsuite/tools'
Use 'make check' to run the tests.
run 'make check' to run tests
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/..../sane-backends/testsuite/tools'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/.../sane-backends/testsuite'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/..../sane-backends/testsuite'
Use 'make test' to run the tests.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/.../sane-backends/testsuite'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/.../sane-backends'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/.../sane-backends'
```

whats wrong with all-am???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it, make says what it does, if it has nothing to do, it just says "nothing to do", thanks to all.